# Interrogation about the relationship between Diego cells and Long Running Processes

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am in reference to the official CloudFoundry documentation about Diego (see [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-design-notes#what-are-all-these-repos-and-what-do-they-do)).

My question relates specifically to diego cells and their relationship with the running jobs (LRPs and Tasks).

I am not sure from reading the documentation whether one cell can run several LRPs at a given time. Can someone please clarify the cardinality of the relation between a cell and running LRPs please?

From reading the following documenation about auctions (see [here](http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/concepts/diego/diego-auction.html#auction)) one can think that a cell runs several LRPs at a given time. Is that the case?

If so how is container isolation achieved?

What do the **grey squares** represent in the image (see ***diego***, ***cell***, ***garden-linux***) below?

[image: diego architecture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Diego Cell is a large VM. If you look closely, the diagram shows 5 cells stacked on top of each other, representing a 5-VM deployment.

A Diego Cell can host many containers, and uses the container implementation to achieve isolation. In the diagram, the top cell is hosting 18 containers (the grey boxes). Each LRP and Task runs inside its own container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It clarifies that a **VM is not a container**. I initially had the misconception that a VM **was** a container...